# Set all status checks to be required as branch protection using the Github API

Tags: api, github

I would like to set all status checks that are available to be required for a branch using the Github API.

However, I cannot find a way to retrieve all possible status checks names nor (preferably) just setting all of them to be required.

How can I achieve this?

Cheers